# spring cloud secured gateway ratelimiting not allowing permitall urls

Tags: spring, security, cloud, microservices, gateway

I was trying to apply rate limiting on my spring cloud gateway which is secured through oauth2 and keycloak. the gateway sits in front of 3 microservices. each microservice exposes openapi3 config. in both gateway and microservices made the url to openapi3 config as public. but when i followed instruction to apply rate limiting using redis the public urls are not public anymore and getting 403 forbidden.

gateway security -->

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class WebFluxSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity serverHttpSecurity) {
        serverHttpSecurity.authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange
                .pathMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**",
                    "/employee/v3/api-docs/**",
                    "/department/v3/api-docs/**",
                    "/organization/v3/api-docs/**",
                    "/webjars/swagger-ui/**",
                    "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(ServerHttpSecurity.OAuth2ResourceServerSpec::jwt);

        serverHttpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        serverHttpSecurity.formLogin().disable();
        serverHttpSecurity.httpBasic().disable();
        return serverHttpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

Rate limiting config -->

```
@Configuration
public class RateLimitingConfig {

    /*
     * NOTE: this stops all unauthenticated access :(
     * need a way to allow public permitted urls from this. but how!
     */
    @Bean
    KeyResolver userKeyResolver() {
        return exchange -> ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(ctx -> ctx.getAuthentication().getPrincipal().toString());
    }
}
```

microservice security config -->

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //NOTE: this is to configure authorization
        http.authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.formLogin().disable();
        http.httpBasic().disable();
    }
}
```

the rate limiting is working properly for authenticated user but my permit all methods are not permitted by the gateway anymore.

how can i enforce rate limiting for private urls and also expose public urls to unauthenticated users?

here is the full code base -
https://github.com/tareqmy/springcloudexamples